# Making a command-line program "full screen"

Tags: ruby, bash, shell, terminal, fullscreen

I am wondering how to create the appearance of a "full-screen" window inside a shell, as in vim, emacs, etc. Is it possible to do this programmatically in Ruby? And how platform-dependent would that be?

Edit: I am not looking for how to make my *shell* go full-screen. I'm looking for a way to hide the previous commands entered and "fill" the shell screen with an app. It's for an installer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're probably looking for is [ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) or [S-Lang](http://www.jedsoft.org/slang/docs.html) support to provide your full [TUI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_user_interface) experience.

Ruby's `gem` environment provides several gems that might be worth exploring:

```
$ gem list --remote | grep -i curses
cursesx (003)
ffi-ncurses (0.4.0)
ncurses (0.9.1)
ncurses-ruby (1.2.1)
ncursesw (1.2.4.3)
snowleopard-ncurses (1.2.4)
```

The author of the [`rbcurse`](https://github.com/rkumar/rbcurse/tree/master19) package recommends using the [`ncurses-ruby` gem](http://ncurses-ruby.berlios.de/). `rbcurse` provides some pre-written widgets and the ability to write new widgets in the same style -- it looks mighty useful.

I haven't yet found any S-Lang bindings for Ruby; based on the project's focus on providing a language interpreter, I just don't think it'll be easy to build Ruby bindings. Pity, because many application authors do prefer S-Lang over ncurses.

Comment: Ah, TUI! that was the word I was looking for but couldn't find. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ncurses` for things like that. It provides an abstraction layer to your terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Although there are many more cross platform and elegant soulution, the following works on Linux, and should work on other Unixes too:

```
system("clear")
```

If you are on Windows, this may work (untested):

```
system("cls")
```

If you want to make an application that can update its interface, you can maintain some sort of array of chars:

```
colArr=[]
columNum.each {colArr<<[]}
#fill colArr
system("clear")
print colArr
#Every time you change it, call system("clear") then print colArr
```

This is pretty manual, but it works for simple TUIs.

Answer (score 0):

try to press "F11" key..or you can go to preferences > display setting
I just find a thread that talking about this..try to go [here](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/214526)

Comment: The link you've provided is for GTK-based _graphical_ interfaces, not terminal interfaces. Can you suggest something more along the lines of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_user_interface ?